# After adding text can't remove with backspace

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Hello I am working on text editor.
I have this code for adding parentheses:

```
char? lastChar = null;
if (richTextBox.Text != "")
{
    lastChar = richTextBox.Text[richTextBox.TextLength - 1];
}
if(lastChar == '(')
{
    richTextBox.AppendText(")");
}
```

And when its add these parentheses its cant be deleted with backspace.

Comment: It is deleted but your code is presumably adding it again immediately as `lastChar == '('` becomes true.  In a keyboard event you would filter and handle deletes.

Comment: using the debugger would be highly encouraged @MineGame159 at this point.. have you done that yet...? also change this line `richTextBox.Text != ""` to `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBox.Text)` instead

Comment: Doesn't RichTextBox have keyboard support built in?

Comment: Using one of the many existing editor components (Telerik, DevEpxress, Scintilla.NET, etc.) would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't delete it is because as soon as you press `Backspace`, your text ends with `'('` again, and you append another `')'`. To disable this, we need to track whether or not the key pressed was the `Backspace` key, and if so, skip your logic (allowing the user to backspace over the auto-appended `')'` character and enter some text).

Assuming your code is in the `TextChanged` event, one thing you could do is create a private variable that gets set in the `KeyDown` event if the key was Backspace, which you would then check in the `TextChanged` event.

As a bonus, I simplified your existing code to one line :)

```
private bool lastKeyPressedWasBackspace;

private void richTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    lastKeyPressedWasBackspace = e.KeyCode == Keys.Back;
}

private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!lastKeyPressedWasBackspace && richTextBox.Text.EndsWith("("))
    {
        richTextBox.AppendText(")");
    }
}
```